# Spring Security Login Page UI issues

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am new to Grails.

I followed the instructions to install `SpringSecurityPlugin (version 2.0:RC2)` and executed the command:

```
grails s2-quickstart User Role
```

that is supossed to generate among other files: `LoginController` and `LogoutController`, but these controllers are not being generated in `grails-app/controllers` or any other directory into the project

however i want to change default login ui of SpringSecurityPlugin to a new ui which matches my web theme..

Comment: grails s2-quickstart User Role should create domains and controllers. Try to make refresh-dependencies command. To change login UI you need to customize `login\auth.gsp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controllers and GSPs are part of the plugin in 2.0. If you want to customize them copy them from the installed plugin directory to your project in the same folders and make the changes there. App files always override plugin files because the plugins are compiled first, then the app, so the app's files take precedence.